# Replace value of column by index value

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have this dataframe:

| Index | id | 1-t | 2-t | 3-t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | 0 | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

The value in columns "-t" is the id, and I want to replace this value with the index value. I have 100 columns to replace (n columns -t), I tried using loop FOR with .loc but it did not work.

Does anyone help me?

Output expected:

| Index | id | 1-t | 2-t | 3-t |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-05 | 0 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |
| 2022-01-01 | 5 | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-02 |

Comment: I don't fully understand what your expected output is. Please add an example of the expected output.

Comment: @Puff I edited the question with the expected output, I appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like the following:

```py
            id  1-t  2-t  3-t
Index                        
2022-01-06   0    5    4    2
2022-01-05   1    3    5    4
2022-01-04   2    4    3    5
2022-01-03   3    3    0    1
2022-01-02   4    2    3    0
2022-01-01   5    1    2    4
```

i.e. what you labeled Index in your table above is the actual index of the Pandas dataframe, all you need to do is use the [`Dataframe.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) routine like so:

```py
for col in data.filter(like='-t'):
    data[col] = data.index[data[col]]

print(data)
#            id         1-t         2-t         3-t
#Index                                             
#2022-01-06   0  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-04
#2022-01-05   1  2022-01-03  2022-01-01  2022-01-02
#2022-01-04   2  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  2022-01-01
#2022-01-03   3  2022-01-03  2022-01-06  2022-01-05
#2022-01-02   4  2022-01-04  2022-01-03  2022-01-06
#2022-01-01   5  2022-01-05  2022-01-04  2022-01-02
```

there might even be a way to replace all the columns at once. In case `Index` is just the name of a column, replace `data.index` by `data.Index`.

EDIT: I forgot to use the index value in the column. Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

```
for nm in df.columns:
    if nm.endswith("-t"):
        tmp = df.Index[df.loc[:, nm]]
        tmp.index = df.index
        df.loc[:, nm] = tmp
df
#         Index  id         1-t         2-t         3-t
# 0  2022-01-06   0  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-04
# 1  2022-01-05   1  2022-01-03  2022-01-01  2022-01-02
# 2  2022-01-04   2  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  2022-01-01
# 3  2022-01-03   3  2022-01-03  2022-01-06  2022-01-05
# 4  2022-01-02   4  2022-01-04  2022-01-03  2022-01-06
# 5  2022-01-01   5  2022-01-05  2022-01-04  2022-01-02
```

OR

```
def foo(i, s):
    ans = i[s]
    ans.index = i.index
    return ans

df.apply(lambda x: foo(df.Index, x) if x.name.endswith("-t") else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way by using `replace()`:

```
d = dict(zip(df['id'],df['Index']))
df.replace({i:d for i in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('-t')]})
```

Output:

```
        Index  id         1-t         2-t         3-t
0  2022-01-06   0  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-04
1  2022-01-05   1  2022-01-03  2022-01-01  2022-01-02
2  2022-01-04   2  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  2022-01-01
3  2022-01-03   3  2022-01-03  2022-01-06  2022-01-05
4  2022-01-02   4  2022-01-04  2022-01-03  2022-01-06
5  2022-01-01   5  2022-01-05  2022-01-04  2022-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i,"1-t"]=df.loc[df.loc[i,"1-t"],"Index"]
    df.loc[i,"2-t"]=df.loc[df.loc[i,"2-t"],"Index"]
    df.loc[i,"3-t"]=df.loc[df.loc[i,"3-t"],"Index"]
```